# I am unable to start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I start the Rails server I get the following error:

```
$ rails s -p 8080       
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'                        
      from /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_threadly/threadly/bin/rails:8:in `require'                                          
      from /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_threadly/threadly/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'                                 
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'                                 
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'                                 
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'                                
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'                                        
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'                                     
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'                                      
      from /home/ccuser/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'                          
      from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'                                                
      from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'                                                
      from /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_threadly/threadly/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'                               
      from bin/rails:3:in `load'                                                                                                  
      from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As short hand, "rails s" starts the server as well as "rails server". The space inbetween is required. Also, I would also strongly suggest Rails development on non Windows platforms. A handful of gems are not compatible with windows versions, so loading a virtual machine with ubuntu will help you in the long run for sure.

I started with Rails development on Windows and instantly ran into trouble loading MySQL gems and others so I switched to Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM and it's been fantastic to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

your command is wrong, It's `rails server`  but not `railsserver`